# Is it possible to only watch changes to files in My Drive and how to intepret notification requests

Tags: google-drive-api

The new [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/push#watch) feature is really awesome! However, when watching changes, the notifications received are noisy. It seems that specifying includeSubscribed=false parameter in the watch request does not exclude changes to subscribed files (shared with me). Also, the notifications request received have strange change ids. For example, I received 11925, 11927, 11929, 11930, 11932, 11931, some of which are changes to subscribed files. However, if I make a changes.list request with startChangeId=11925, I only get 11925, 11926, 11932 (largestChangeId seems to increase to the largest id received in notifications though).

Does it mean that push notifications are only intended for notifications, not for information? Or is it a bug in this API?

In addition (sorry to ask several questions in one post), I found that the `id` property of a watch request cannot contain `'/'`, but it's not mentioned in the docs:

> An id property string that uniquely identifies this new notification channel within your project. We recommend that you use a universally unique identifier (UUID) or any similar unique string. Maximum length: 64 characters.

and what characters are acceptable in watch channel ids?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly correct. The push notifications are only notifications, not information for obvious privacy reasons. It is your responsibility to fetch the information yourself using whatever auth token you have stored for the user.

If you are thinking of using non-ascii characters, I would likely just pass a byte string that has been encoded from whatever you have. That way you can decode it later as it will be returned untouched.